# .NET Custom Exception not being caught where expected

Tags: .net, exception

This feels like a stupid question but I have a console app that is supposed to be throwing and handling a custom exception type.  For some reason it's falling through to the general Exception catch and I'm not sure why.

The Main program:

```
try
{
    result = MyService.ExecuteSearch(paramItems);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    // Catch time out exceptions here
}
catch (SearchAnticipatedException ex)
{
    // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO BE WITH MY CUSTOM EXCEPTION & MESSAGE
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // THE ORIGINAL EXCEPTION IS BEING CAUGHT HERE 
}
```

The main guts of my logic catches an EndpointNotFoundException and I'm trying to instead of throwing that one - throw my custom exception with a more meaningful message (and other information).  But instead the original endpoingnotfoundexception is being handled in that Catch (Exception ex) block.

```
 try
 {
          // do some logic
          ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
 }
 catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException ex)
 {
      throw new SearchAnticipatedException(ServiceState.Critical, hostName, ex);
 }
 catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex)
 {
      throw new SearchAnticipatedException(ServiceState.Critical, hostName, ex);
 }
 finally
 {
    if (((IClientChannel)proxy).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
    {
         factory.Abort();
         ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
    }
 }
```

If I comment out the general exception at the bottom of the main section then it gets caught by the right block - I thought it would be caught by the more specific exception first and if it didn't match any of those it would fall into the last general sort of block.

Hopefully it's just something small I've stuffed up :)

My exception class looks like:

```
 class SearchAnticipatedException : System.Exception
    {
        public int ServiceStateCode { get; set; }

        public SearchAnticipatedException(MyService.ServiceState serviceState, string message, Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException)
        {
            ServiceStateCode = (int)serviceState;
        }

        public static string FormatExceptionMessage(string message, MyService.ServiceState serviceState)
        {
            return serviceState.ToString().ToUpper() + SearchResult.CODE_MESSAGE_DELIMITER + message;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - turns out that if there was an endpointNoutFoundException then I couldn't check the status of the channel.  ie. if it was open I wanted to close it.  It was throwing an exception in the finally block :)

Instead am just going to call the factory.abort().

```
finally
{
   factory.Abort();
}
```

As I set a timeout value I wanted to make sure that if a Timeout Exception occurred then any connection was closed down properly.

Comment: So let me be clear.  You did not verify what exception was being thrown before you posted the proper exception was not being caught.

Comment: Regardless of what had happened I wanted the finally to clean up any potentially open connections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly, because I thought that the first matching catch clause would take precedence, but you might have more success if you do it like this instead:

```
try 
{ 
   ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     if (ex is TimeoutException)
     {
        ...
     }
     else if (ex is SearchAnticipatedException)
     {
        ...
     }
     else
     {
         ...
     }
}
finally
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks - figured out it was another exception being thrown in the finally block.  I figured there was something dumb going on if the standard exception handling wasn't kicking in :)